# How to disable model.store in can.js

Tags: canjs, canjs-model, canjs-list

Shifted to REST architecture, so don't need to store those anymore.
Is there a way how to disable the [model storing](https://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.store.html) at all?

Answer (score 0):

We can clear store before get data from REST

```
model.store = {};
```